# Two of my drain spouts from the gutters on my house go down into holes in the ground. Where does _that_ lead?

Tags: drainage, gutters

I don't know how to figure out where this leads. Where is the water from my gutter being drained off to? (Or I mean, how do I figure out the answer to this question?) I do not know of any outlet anywhere in my yard where this water might be coming out.

When the guy redid my gutters several months ago, I asked him where this leads and, don't be mad, but he answered right when some loud noises happened and I couldn't hear him and I just nodded and figured I'd figure it out later........[image]

Answer (score 1):

The downspouts drain to a below-grade sower line that ends up in a catch basin, depends on your locality, the catch basin can be in front or the back of your house. The collected water is then transferred to the public sewerage line after the debris has settled in the catch basin.

Comment: Or they lead to a dry well that has no connection to the sewer system. Or any number of other possible things, which can only be ascertained for certain by digging to verify what, exactly, you have. Though, I suppose shoving a sewer camera down them might yield some insight without digging them up. So, this is one *possible* case, among *many.*

Comment: Good point. I omit the question "Or I mean, how do I figure out the answer to this question?" The catch basin is rather easy to spot, it is a 30"-36" round shaft with a metal cover on top. Without that, it is likely to end up a dry well as pointed out by Ecnerwal. But instead of digging, it is better to call your plumber who did work for you, or the city to find out the local drainage system.

Comment: @Ecnerwal You should provide it as the answer.